# Does water level determine the amount of power lost?

Tags: one-piece

In the left image, you can see that Luffy and Brook have their powers drained. However in the right image, both Hancock and Luffy are in standing water but seem to keep their powers.

[image: Screencap from anime of Brook and Luffy Bathing with powers drained]
[image: Screencap from anime of Boa Hancock and Luffy in the bath]

So, does the amount of power they lose depend on the water level?

Comment: Well, we don't actually see Luffy and Boa maintaining their powers, we just see them not weakened, so that might have a tie-in.

Comment: What episode is the first picture from?

Comment: @Cyberson in that specific episode, i do believe that bon tried to use her love beam on Luffy and fails but i'm not sure if she was standing in water or not

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade the first picture is from One Piece Film: Z, thanks by the way for editing, i don't know how to edit

Comment: @Dragon I believe that was not when she was in the water, because the beam did fire it just didn't do anything.

Comment: @Cyberson i don't think that's the case, in this link, there is a question on this site about why hancock's didn't work on luffy, take a look if you wish but it definitely wasn't because hancock was standing in water http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5896/why-didnt-boa-hancocks-attack-affect-luffy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I read and what I remember:

- Rain normally doesn't have an effect.
- If the Devil Fruit user's body is mostly out of water, then they get weakened a bit.
- If the user is totally/mostly in the water, they normally can't move.
- Seastone has an effect like that of being totally in water.

The difference of the above pictures: on the left, Luffy and Brook are mostly in water, so they are very weak; on the right, Boa Hancock and Luffy are only standing in knee-deep water, so they don't lose too much power.

Answer (score 1):

I think the water level is not important, just because when some water is touching them they start losing their power. I think the most important think is the time they are being in contact with it.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't believe that's the case because whenever a devil fruit user touches the ocean or the sea stone, they start loosing their power, they may still have enough power to defeat someone, but they do loose their power just from touching it. SPOILER this is show in the bit just after the two year gap where they are underwater trying to get to the mermaid land.